# (String: AnyObject) does not have a member named 'subscript'

Tags: swift

I've been through similar questions but still do not understand why my code is throwing an error.

```
var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
dict["participants"] = ["foo", "bar"]
dict["participants"][0] = "baz"
```

The error is on line 3: `(String: AnyObject) does not have a member named 'subscript'`

I'm setting the `participants` key to an array and then trying to update the first element of it without any luck. The code above is shortened for example purposes, but I am using `[String:AnyObject]` because it is not only arrays that are stored in the dictionary.

It's probably something really trivial but I am still new to Swift. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Your dictionary values are typed as AnyObject. I know *you* know that this value is a string array, but Swift does not know that; it knows only what you told it, that this is an AnyObject. But AnyObject can't be subscripted (in fact, you can't do much with it at all). If you want to use subscripting, you need to tell Swift that this is not an AnyObject but rather an Array of some sort (here, an array of String).

There is then a second problem, which is that `dict["participants"]` is not in fact even an AnyObject - it is an *Optional* wrapping an AnyObject. So you will have to unwrap it *and* cast it in order to subscript it.

There is then a third problem, which is that you can't mutate an array value inside a dictionary in place. You will have to extract the value, mutate it, and then replace it.

So, your entire code will look like this:

```
var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
dict["participants"] = ["foo", "bar"]
var arr = dict["participants"] as [String] // unwrap the optional and cast
arr[0] = "baz" // now we can subscript!
dict["participants"] = arr // but now we have to write back into the dict
```

*Extra for experts*: If you want to be disgustingly cool and Swifty (and who doesn't??), you can perform the mutation and the assignment in one move by using a define-and-call anonymous function, like this:

```
var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
dict["participants"] = ["foo", "bar"]
dict["participants"] = {
    var arr = dict["participants"] as [String]
    arr[0] = "baz"
    return arr
}()
```

Comment: Can you explain why you typed `dict` as `[String:AnyObject]` in the first place? I'm not saying there's no reason to do so, but if every value is going to an array of String you might as well say so up front. Otherwise, you will have to cast.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I should have been clearer about that. The code above is more for example purposes but there will not always be an array. In some cases it will have other data types. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Fenda Perfectly reasonable; this happens all the time. But then you do need to cast. I've updated my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @Fenda I've just written a Swift tutorial that might help you: you could start here, with the Dictionary section: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_dictionary But you will want to work your way backwards to the Array section, the AnyObject section, and eventually, perhaps, the Optionals section.

Comment: Another thing to watch out for is that an Array in Swift is not necessarily an object.  Try for example:   `var my_map : [String:AnyObject] = [ "foo" : [1, 2, 3, 4] ]
repl.swift:1:37: error: '[String : Array<Int>]' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'`.  In this case, the problem is that Array<Int> (aka. [Int]) is a Value type and not an object at all.  In your code example, the compiler was able to take your array of strings and interpret it as an NSArray of NSStrings, but your code won't work in general.

Comment: **1)** When you say 'optional wrapping', do you mean you actually create an optional out of something that wasn't an optional before? Why would you want to *create* an optional? Do you do that because there is a chance that that subscript could be `nil`? **2)**  We can't just use `!` because it won't know to what type (here `[string]`) it should unwrap it to? But with using `as [string]` we will inform the compiler? **PS:** Matt you have given me and the community so many good answers. Thank you man! I see myself obligated to buy your book. Currently I am on a tight  budget. Soon I won't be...