# How to delete group data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have Dictionary and I am adding to tableView.

```
 let myArray = [["name": "First element", "foo": "bar","GroupID":"1"], ["name": "First element", "foo": "bar","GroupID":"1"],["name": "Second element", "foo": "bar","GroupID":"2"], ["name": "Second element", "foo": "bar","GroupID":"2"]]
```

In this dictionary I have key `GroupID`.

Is it possible that I can get dictionary data whose `GroupID = %@`?

I want to filter data based on grouping

Suppose I have four data, and group id is same in two data. I want to delete all data whose GroupID is same from dictionary.

If `groupid == 1` than data will be deleted from dictionary whose `GroupID == 1` and tableview will reload data.

I am doing this because I want to delete group data.

Comment: Do you want your array without repeating groupid? or you want your array without those groupid which are repeating ?

Comment: @Rajat thanks for quick response. actually i have main and sub products. each main products have its subitems.when i delete main item,its subitems also should be deleted. for that i think i should use groupid for that. is this right?

Comment: Ok so after deleting Item all the subitems with that groupid should be removed, Right ?

Comment: @Rajat Exactly.

Comment: @Rajat i have dynamic products.main and its sub products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` on your `Array` to remove those dictionaries from your array, check this example

```
var subitems: [[String:String]] = [
    ["groupid": "1", "b": "2"],
    ["groupid": "3", "b": "4"],
    ["groupid": "1", "b": "6"]
]

var filteredSubitems = subitems.filter{
    $0["groupid"] != "1" // change with your groupid
}

print(filteredSubitems)
```

Comment: You can remove the brackets around the filter block too.

Comment: let productDict  = arrProductCart[sender.tag] as! [String: AnyObject]
       print(productDict)
        
        var filteredSubitems = productDict.filter{
            $0["groupid"] != "1" // change with your groupid
        }

Comment: i am getting issue with my array.(String, AnyObject)' has no subscript members

Comment: @KrutarthPatel use this `$0["groupid"] as! String != "1"`

Comment: @Rajat Same error. syntax issue due to swift version?

Comment: I am using swift3 what is your version ? Also check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013901/string-anyobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript

Comment: @Rajat Swift 2.3 or under

Comment: @Rajat can you give me syntax?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel sorry man I am not able to check it with swift2.3, also can you do one thing , change this `[String: AnyObject]` to this `[String: String]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127797/discussion-between-krutarth-patel-and-rajat).

Comment: means i have to convert [String: AnyObject] to [[String:String]]

Comment: @KrutarthPatel as per your question you have asked about **how to delete group data in swift** and i have provided you answer about that, now if you are getting another error then you can post it as another question, i have also suggested a link about the error which you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
var index = 0
for element in myArray {
    if element["GroupID"] == "1" {
        myArray.remove(at: 0)
        index += 1
    } else {
        index += 1
    }
}

print(myArray):
```

It prints out:

> [["name": "Second element", "GroupID": "2", "foo": "bar"], ["name":
>   "Second element", "GroupID": "2", "foo": "bar"]]

Good luck!

Comment: Value of type '[Dictionary<String, String>]' has no member 'remove'

Comment: Did you import `Foundation` or `UIKit`?

Comment: Is the array you wrote in the question your actual array? Can you put the actual one out?

Comment: Oh I see, your are using Swift 2.3 or under, this is Swift 3.0

Comment: No this is not actual array.

Comment: in my array there is no field of GroupId. i use this logic to delete

Comment: change `let myArray` to `var myArray`